# Баклажан или баклажанов?

Tags: склонение, множественное-число

Вчера в одном кафе увидел надпись из разряда "закуска из баклаж**ан**". Снисходительно улыбнулся, но на всякий случай заглянул в словари и с удивлением обнаружил, что можно писать/говорить и "баклаж**анов**", и "баклаж**ан**".

Почему тут появилась (и сохраняется) вариативность? Какой из вариантов более грамотный?

Answer (score 2):

"Почему" - это вопрос несколько опрометчивый. Ибо на все такие вопросы надо отвечать "Промыслом Божиим". Ну нет тут юридически точного объяснения и быть не может, ибо нет причинно-следственной связи.  Это во-первых.

Во-вторых, допустимость этой формы родительного множественного признается далеко не всеми. Когда ссылаетесь на "Грамоту", называйте все-таки конкретный словарь. "Грамота" словарей не пишет, а у авторов, на ней представленных, могут быть (и есть) совершенно разные мнения.

И в-третьих. Очень может быть, что мы наблюдаем самое начало зарождения новой падежной формы (ну или "протопадежной"). Что это такое, сейчас поясню. Существует - и это уже почти не оспаривается - так называемая "счетная форма" - падежный вариант родительного, используемый при числительных. Нормативным он безусловно является для некоторых единиц измерений: пять **киловатт**, десять **стерадиан**, двести **ангстрем**.

У некоторых многосложных существительных, обозначающих плоды и фрукты (апельсин, мандарин, помидор) прослеживается тенденция к использованию подобной же формы, что пока не является нормативным (даже на уровне допустимости), но на грани (пять помидор). И вот эта преднормативная форма все чаще выходит за рамки счетной - и используется с предлогом ИЗ для обозначения исходного материала, сырья (из чего сделано, изготовлено). Тоже, естественно, вне нормативности пока. Есть предположение, что "баклажан" просто немного обогнал своих собратьев на этом пути.

Тому способствовал, возможно, сам вид слова. Оно было не очень привычно до самого недавнего времени (имелись варианты бандижан, бандиджан, бадижан и другие, у них были и "женские" варианты). Видимо, язык для необкатанного слова предпочел более краткую возможность.

К сожалению, словари не позволяют судить о том,  в каких случаях допустимо использование формы "баклажан". Но лично мне эта форма "из баклажан" / "пять баклажан" в других случаях родительного режет слух куда больше. Хотя еще "нет баклажан" тоже не так дико звучит. Но в остальных случаях - совсем не ласкает ухо.

Comment: Интересная мысль.

Comment: @Aer *"Протопадеж" это не партитив случайно?)* - партитив это давно уже развившаяся падежная форма. Зализняк её вообще полноценным падежом считает. К тому же она историческая, а не новообразованная. Вот всякие там ждательный, отделительный и  прочие - это то, что я назвал протопадежом.

Comment: @Aer если вы не согласны с моим названием, предложите другое, я не претендую на терминологию. А если с тем, что я сказал, так с чем конкретно?! Я же именно то, что написал, назвал таким термином. Значит, для несогласия надо хотя бы указать, чего именно вам представляется некорректным. А то наш разговор переходит в какую-то умохрительную плоскость. **Я назвал свою собаку Жучкой" - "Я не согласен, в ней нет ничего от Жучки"* Так что ли? Вы покажите, что у меня нет "собаки" или что она не моя - вот это будет разговор более или менее содержательный.

Comment: @Aer Вам кажется. Это ВЫ называете. Читайте внимательно. Партитив - вполне состоявшаяся падежная форма. Вопрос только в том, считать ли её самостоятельным падежом или вариантом родительного.

Answer (score 1):

Строгая литературная норма для р.п. мн. ч. - "баклажанов". В разговорной речи допустим вариант "баклажан".

Подобный вопрос был на грамота.ру - см. [270120](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=270120)

[Викисловарь для леммы "баклажан"](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BD) указывает обе формы как равноправные, словарь опенкорпоры (на базе Зализняка) помечает словоформу "[баклажан](http://opencorpora.org/dict.php?act=edit&id=22605)" как Infr, разговорную.

Остаётся открытым вопрос, откуда появилась вариативность.

Answer (score 0):

Из словаря:

БАКЛАЖАН; мн. род. -ов и (разг.) -жан;

ПОМИДОР; мн. род. помидоров; м.

АПЕЛЬСИН; мн. род. -ов;

Вообще говоря, для сущ. **м.р.** окончание ОВ является **основным**,  а нулевое окончание - **вариантным**, причем  в тематической группе, связанной с названиями плодов/овощей, **вариантное окончание не применяется.**

Для сравнения: яблоко (ср.р.) - яблок, груша - (ж.р) - груш, здесь **нулевое окончание является основным.**

Почему для баклажанов сделано исключение - непонятно, но в любом случае, это пока не литературный, а разговорный вариант.  Возможно, форма "баклажанов" слишком "длинна" для разговорной речи. Но есть и еще объяснение. Давайте сравним:  килограмм баклажан(ов) - закуска из баклажан. **Наличие предлога во втором случае исключает смешение двух форм**: один баклажан (ед.ч.) - килограмм баклажан (мн.ч. Р.п.). Поэтому нулевое окончание чаще применяется при наличии предлога.

Таким образом, **вариативность появляется из реального словоупотребления**,  наличие которого приходится фиксировать в словарях.

А вот и примеры: Овощную икру **из баклажан** можно сделать без кабачков, моркови и капусты, взяв лишь помидоры и сладкий болгарский перец. [Что у нас на обед (2000)].  Блюда **из баклажан**: салат **из баклажан** со сладким перцем.

Comment: немного не понял Ваш пример про килограмм баклажан(ов) и закуску из баклажан(ов). Вы имеете в виду, что при наличии предлога необходимость "длинного" варианта с окончанием отпадает?

Comment: ОСНОВНЫЕ окончание  в Р.п. мн.ч.: 1 скл: стена - стен, 2  скл., м. р.: стол - столов, 2 скл., ср. р.:  окна - окон.Обратим внимание на следующую закономерность: если в начальной форме слово имеет  ненулевое окончание (стена, окно), то в Р.п. окончание нулевое (стен, окон), и наоборот: при нулевом окончании в начальной форме (стол) наблюдается ненулевое окончание ОВ в Р.п.  (столов).

Comment: Разные окончания (нулевое и ненулевое) обеспечивают РАЗЛИЧЕНИЕ двух форм существительного: начальной формы и формы мн. числа Р.п. (стол – столов, но: стена – стен). Из этого следует: покупать килограмм апельсин, мандарин, баклажан - неясное сочетание,  совпадение форм, а икра из баклажан - здесь всё понятно.

Comment: @ Sibylla, я правильно понимаю, что Вы полагаете, что при наличии предлога родительный падеж более явный, поэтому и меньше неясности?

Comment: Это мое предположение. Форма "из баклажан" часто встречается в литературе кулинарной тематики, поэтому логично представить, что перешли от строгой нормы "только баклажанов" к признанию разговорного варианта "баклажан".  В 1990 году баклажаны никак не выделялись из группы овощей/фруктов, нулевое окончание считалось ненормативным.